# Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, orm, ebean

I am getting the below error.

> The default EbeanServer has not been defined? This is normally set via the ebean.datasource.default property. Otherwise it should be registered programmatically via registerServer()

In application.conf file I do have

> ebean.default = ["models.*"]

Then too this error is coming.
Not able to run my script.
How to resolve this?
I am using Ebean ORM with MySQL.